# Perform a VLOOKUP inside an IF condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to VLOOKUP a value X in a table when (IF) a column Y of that table is INFERIOR to a value Z.

Writing this formula is returning the first value of the table and not the one I need:
`=IF(PI_UWF!S:S < Search!$L$19 ; VLOOKUP(O18;PI_UWF!$C:$Q;15;FALSE) ; "boh")`

- Value X = `VLOOKUP(O18;PI_UWF!$C:$Q;15;FALSE)`
- Column Y = `PI_UWF!S:S`
- Value Z = `Search!$L$19`

How can I do it?

Comment: The first problem I see is: if S:S < ?. You cannot evaluate all S:S and ask if any value in S:S is less than. IF will not evaluate each cell in S.

Comment: If you could produce some work and post it up in a table and show exactly what you are looking for then I'd be willing to help. Right now it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You follow the wrong logic, checking the criteria outside of `VLOOKUP` won't work.

Instead of `VLOOKUP` use INDEX and MATCH, that way you can create a more flexible formula:

`=INDEX(PI_UWF!Q:Q;MATCH(O18,IF(PI_UWF!S:S<Search!L19,PI_UWF!C:C,""),0))`
It's an array formula, so press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after inserting it.

How it works:

- `IF(PI_UWF!S:S<Search!L19,PI_UWF!C:C,"")` - selects the value from C:C only if S:S inferior to Search!L19
- `MATCH(O18,IF(...),0)` - matches the value from the filtered list
- `=INDEX(PI_UWF!Q:Q;MATCH(...))` - selects the right value from Q:Q

(as I don't have sample data, I couldn't check the solution, it may have minor issues, but the concept is right).

Answer (score 0):

It's not relibale to use `=IF(PI_UWF!S:S < Search!$L$19;;)` 
It wouldn't know if you want to compare it to the sum of the column, or a single value. And will be quite unreliable.

There are a lot of functions you could use, depending on what you want to do.
If you want to compare `Z` to the **sum** of `Y` you could use `SUM()`

With this you could replace `PI_UWF!S:S` with `SUM(PI_UWF!S:S)` which would give you:

```
=IF(SUM(PI_UWF!S:S) < Search!$L$19 ; VLOOKUP(O18;PI_UWF!$C:$Q;15;FALSE) ; "boh")
```

It's more likely that you want to compare `Z` to **every single** cell of `Y`.
For this you could use something like `COUNTIF(range, criteria)` .

`=COUNTIF(PI_UWF!S:S;">="&Search!$L$19)` Will count the number of cells in `Y` with a value equal to or higher than `Z`.
If this value is 0, you know that every cell in `Y` is less than `Z`. That means:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(PI_UWF!S:S;">="&Search!$L$19)>0;"Not inferior";"Inferior")
```

or in your case

```
=IF(COUNTIF(PI_UWF!S:S;">="&Search!$L$19)>0;"boh";VLOOKUP(O18;PI_UWF!$C:$Q;15;FALSE))
```

Good luck!